# FreeNAS zpool not found

Tags: storage, nas, freenas

Consider me as new in `FreeNAS` storage.

Disk failure on our `FreeNAS 8.3` After rebuilding and replacing one disk on the RAID we are unable to access or mount the data.

There are 8 X 3TB HDDs on the `FreeNAS` Server and there is a zpool of 16TB.

The output is below.

> freenas# camcontrol devlist
>          at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (pass0,cd0)
>
> freenas# glabel status
>             Name  Status  Components
>    ufs/FreeNASs3     N/A  mfid0s3
>    ufs/FreeNASs4     N/A  mfid0s4
>   ufs/FreeNASs1a     N/A  mfid0s1a
>
> freenas# gpart show
>   =>        63  4294967232  mfid0  MBR  (2.7T)
>             63     1930257      1  freebsd  [active]  (942M)
>        1930320          63         - free -  (31k)
>        1930383     1930257      2  freebsd  (942M)
>        3860640        3024      3  freebsd  (1.5M)
>        3863664       41328      4  freebsd  (20M)
>        3904992  4291062303         - free -  (2T)
>
> =>      0  1930257  mfid0s1  BSD  (942M)
>           0       16           - free -  (8.0k)
>          16  1930241        1  !0  (942M)

Attached image was from logs & this looks like it was having and hardware raid previously.

[image]

> freenas# mfiutil show config
>    mfi0 Configuration: 2 arrays, 2 volumes, 0 spares
>       array 0 of 1 drives:
>           drive  9 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>       array 1 of 7 drives:
>           drive 10 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>           drive 11 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>           drive 12 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>           drive 13 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>           drive 14 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>           drive 15 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>           drive 16 ( 2794G) ONLINE  SATA
>       volume mfid0 (2794G) RAID-0 128k OPTIMAL spans:
>           array 0
>       volume mfid1 (16T) RAID-5 128k OPTIMAL spans:
>           array 1

Comment: Please in the future do take the time to write a coherent post, and do not use & in place of and, it is not professional.

Comment: What's the output of `zpool list` or `zpool status`? Did you simply unplug failed disk and then plug in new one without using`zpool` to take pool offline, replace, etc?

Comment: Did you replace the disk in the GUI? If not, what commands did you run to replace the disk? Can you import the pool? If not, what error message do you get? How are the disks connected? Do you use a hardware RAID? The 8 hard drives don't show up in your abovementioned listings. Are you sure they're properly connected and powered?

Comment: @bdowning for both the commands same output "no pools available". i haven't used zpool command for replacing the disk. Raid was rebuilt from Bios LSI.

Comment: @Marco Yes there is a hardware raid, In Bios I can see all 8 Disk online. In raid 5 7 Hard Disk are participating in Virtual Disk 01. I was unable to import the pool from "zpool import -f" command.

Comment: You [should not](http://www.freenas.org/whats-new/2015/09/freenas-worst-practices.html) have used [hardware raid](http://www.freenas.org/hardware-requirements/) with FreeNAS. ZFS works best if it has direct access to the disks. Your best bet is to get rid of the hardware raid and restore from backup, I guess.

Comment: How to use zfs instead of hardware raid, I have no idea

Comment: Disable the raid function (sometimes called jbod mode) of the controller (if it has that ability) so every disk is presented to the OS individually. Or use a pure HBA instead of a raid controller.

Comment: OK I will remove the vd "volume01" from BIOS.

Comment: now after deleting the hardware raid, how will I get my zfs pool add my new disk to the previous zpool.

Comment: You need to follow both the zfs documentation for creating a pool as well as the documentation for your RAID controller for accessing your disks. Typical access requires creating a mulitple RAID1 virtual disks, each with one disk, for *each* of your disks. Then you can create a zpool and add your virtual discs.

Comment: Is it possible to get my data or it will be gone.

Comment: It will be lost if you break the RAID array and then write to the disks.
Do you have a backup? If so, easiest path is to restore data after creating new zpool/zfs. If not, then you may want to continue trying to rebuild your RAID array, zpool, zfs.

Comment: @bdowning as per the Event logs Of LSI BIOS, I found that in 2014 "VD 0" and "VD01" was created. this confirms that we had a Hardware Raid. I have rebuilt the raid, Now how can I get it mounted under FreeNAS to get my previous data.

Comment: Good, I'm glad to hear it. Please, backup your data, backup your data, backup your data! ZFS replaces hardware raid. You really don't *need* both, but I would suggest you do some reading and research on the topic before attempting to make any changes.

Comment: @bdowning I was able to get the previous status by logs, edited question.